Handling Malformed JSON Output from Language Model
I'm working with a language model (LLM) that generates JSON output, but I'm encountering frequent syntax errors in the generated JSON. The errors typically involve:

Missing colons in key-value pairs
Missing quotation marks around string values
Inconsistent handling of null values

Here's an example of the malformed JSON I'm receiving:
{
 "question": "How challenging is it to manage each of the following instructional elements for your district / school? Please answer on a scale of 1-7, where 1= \"Not at all challenging\" and 7= \"Extremely challenging\"",
 "qstnLabel": "Q13",
 "type": "grid",
 "columns": {
 "[01]1= \"Not at all challenging\": null",
 "[02]2: null",
 "[03]3= \"Extremely challenging\": null"
 },
 "rows": {
 "[01]Administering real-time check for understanding": null,
 "[02]Enabling student collaboration: null",
 "[03]Providing teachers access to any content (paid or teacher-created) in one platform: null"
 }
}

I've attempted to clean this JSON using regex, but while it solves some issues, new errors keep cropping up. Here's my current cleaning function:
import json
import re

def clean_and_parse_json(raw_json_string):
    
    fixed_colons = re.sub(r'("\w+")(\s*)(null|true|false|\d+|"[^"]*")\s*([,}])', r'\1:\3\4', raw_json_string)
    
    # Ensure all string values are properly quoted
    fixed_quotes = re.sub(r':\s*([^"][^\s,}]+)([,}])', r': "\1"\2', fixed_colons)
    
    # Fix null values
    fixed_nulls = fixed_quotes.replace(': null,', ': "null",').replace(': null}', ': "null"}')
    
    
    try:
        parsed_json = json.loads(fixed_nulls)
        return parsed_json
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"Error parsing JSON: {e}")
        print("Cleaned but unparseable JSON:")
        print(fixed_nulls)
        return None

While this function handles some cases, I'm still encountering errors with more complex JSON structures or when the LLM introduces unexpected formatting issues.
Questions:

How can I make this JSON cleaning process more robust?
Are there any libraries or techniques specifically designed for handling malformed JSON from language models?
What strategies can I employ to handle edge cases or unexpected formatting issues?
Is there a more efficient way to approach this problem, perhaps by modifying the LLM's output process itself?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

Don’t expect LLMs to output valid JSON. It’s not something they do. Any semblance to actual JSON is incidental. You can’t reliably “fix JSON”. Ask it to output in some format that doesn’t have strict syntax requirements, like “one item per line” or something.
